# Split the python list of list

Tags: python, list

Hello i am new to python 
i have a list of list,

```
data = [['shop_id', '=', 1],
        ['product_id', '=', 16], ['product_id', '=', 8], ['product_id', '=', 4], ['product_id', '=', 6],
        ['so', '=', 1],['so', '=', 2],
        ['state', '=', u'draft']
       ]
```

and i wanted to a output like,

```
out_put = [[['shop_id', '=', 1]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 16]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 8]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 4]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 6]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 16],['so', '=', 1]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 8],['so', '=', 1]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 4],['so', '=', 1]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 6],['so', '=', 1]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 16],['so', '=', 2]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 8],['so', '=', 2]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 4],['so', '=', 2]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 6],['so', '=', 2]],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 16],['so', '=', 1],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 8],['so', '=', 1],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 4],['so', '=', 1],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 6],['so', '=', 1],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 16],['so', '=', 2],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 8],['so', '=', 2],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 4],['so', '=', 2],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           [['shop_id', '=', 1],['product_id', '=', 6],['so', '=', 2],['state', '=', u'draft']],
           ]
```

i have tried several method but can't find the solution.like

```
for domain in data:
    if domain[0] not in temp:
        final_dom.append(domain)
        print "final_dom :::",final_dom
        temp.append(domain[0])
    else:
        print "adsada"
        final_dom.pop()
        final_dom.append(domain)
        print "final_dom :::",final_dom
```

Comment: Are you sure a list is the right way to go!? Seems like you should be using a dictionary.

Comment: That's... an ugly data structure you want as output, but you may find the `itertools` module helpful. Why do you want this output? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you're missing a `['so', '=', 2]` in `data`

Comment: @DominicKexel ya i missed!

Comment: *i have tried several method but can't find the solution.* You should post what you have tried so others can help you with your code.

Comment: See the powerset recipe: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby, product
from operator import itemgetter

groups = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(data,key=itemgetter(0))]
for i in range(1,len(groups)+1):
    print list(product(*groups[:i]))
```

out:

```
[(['shop_id', '=', 1],)]
[(['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 16]),
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 8]), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 4]), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 6])]
[(['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 16], ['so', '=', 1]), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 16], ['so', '=', 2]),
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 8], ['so', '=', 1]), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 8], ['so', '=', 2]), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 4], ['so', '=', 1]), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 4], ['so', '=', 2]),
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 6], ['so', '=', 1]),
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 6], ['so', '=', 2])]
[(['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 16], ['so', '=', 1], ['state', '=', u'draft']),
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 16], ['so', '=', 2], ['state', '=', u'draft']), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 8], ['so', '=', 1], ['state', '=', u'draft']), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 8], ['so', '=', 2], ['state', '=', u'draft']), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 4], ['so', '=', 1], ['state', '=', u'draft']), 
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 4], ['so', '=', 2], ['state', '=', u'draft']),
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 6], ['so', '=', 1], ['state', '=', u'draft']),
 (['shop_id', '=', 1], ['product_id', '=', 6], ['so', '=', 2], ['state', '=', u'draft'])]
```